# JBoss Seam Unknown context variable name

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, seam

I have a jboss seam project and I have created a Stateless bean named vehicleStockController when i inject bean class to my antoher bean im gettin a warning when I am in eclipse, the validator (by a warning) says Unknown context variable name: vehicleStockController 
when I run the project I get a null pointer exception because is null.

My vehicleStockController bean,

```
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Name("vehicleStockController")
public class VehicleStockControlBean {

    @In
    EntityManager entityManager;
```

and i want to use it from vehicleStockFacade

```
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Name("vehicleStockFacade")
public class VehicleStockFacade {

    @In(create=true)
    VehicleStockControlBean vehicleStockController;
```

I am getting "unknown context variable name: vehicleStockController" 
Does anybody knows whats wrong with this?